# How would I make an executable that contains compressed files, and runs one on execution of the file?

Tags: compression, self-extracting

Ok, so imagine you have a self-extracting compressed file with the following contents:

```
x.exe
images/y.png
sfx/z.wav
```

When a user clicks on the compressed file, it runs `x.exe` instead of extracting everything. Is this possible to do?

Comment: first of all "exe" implies windows but "/" implies NOT windows.  see [this](https://ntsblog.homedev.com.au/index.php/2015/05/14/self-extracting-archive-runs-setup-exe-7zip-sfx-switch/) link for doing this using 7zip (plus addins).. think of x.exe as "setup.exe".. that is where you will find the tools to do this.

Comment: Thank you, @SeñorCMasMas!

Comment: Windows uses backslashes for path delimiters, not forward slashes.  Because a program is "nice enough" to convert them for you doesn't make it a thing. Each and every program needs to implement this on its own.  Read [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/181774/why-windows-uses-backslashes-and-everything-else-uses-forward-slashes/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these directions: https://ntsblog.homedev.com.au/index.php/2015/05/14/self-extracting-archive-runs-setup-exe-7zip-sfx-switch/. Thanks to @SeñorCMasMas!

Comment: Wait two days... then accept this as the answer.  You will get some badly needed points.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: DOUGH!  I forgot to tell him that @DavidPostill.. clearly I am still the student while you remain the teacher. :-)